# permission issue on datadir

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04

[image]I am new to mysql , permission denied to access errorlog. need to grant permission to root.

```
jenner@Selva:~$ mysqld start
2019-10-11T10:16:28.891858Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010139] [Server] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 8161)
2019-10-11T10:16:28.891868Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010142] [Server] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 4000)
2019-10-11T10:16:29.145945Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2019-10-11T10:16:29.145994Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.17) starting as process 30825
2019-10-11T10:16:29.149013Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2019-10-11T10:16:29.149027Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2019-10-11T10:16:29.149121Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010187] [Server] Could not open file '/var/log/mysql/error.log' for error logging: Permission denied
2019-10-11T10:16:29.149230Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-10-11T10:16:29.149350Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.17)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/82374/how-do-i-start-stop-mysql-server

Comment: This question is considerd [offtopic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here..  Try on https://serverfault.com/ or https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RiggsFolly it didnt help